# Problem with erasing elements from the set

Tags: c++, set, erase

I am having troubles with erasing elements from sets. I get `BUILD FAILED` from:

```
n2Ar.erase(it);
n3Ar.erase(it);
```

where `it` is a pointer received from `find()` function: e.g. `it = n2Ar.find(*i);`

The whole listing of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define TESTING_FILE_IN
//#define TESTING_FILE_OUT
//#define DEBUG
//#define SHOW_TIMING

int outputSet(int i) {
    cout << i << endl;
}

/*
 * 
 */
int main() {

    int n1, n2, n3;
    set<int> list, n1Ar, n2Ar, n3Ar;
    set<int>::iterator it;

    scanf("%d", &n1);
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    scanf("%d", &n3);

    int val = 0;

    // Getting lists of voters
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        cin >> val;
        n1Ar.insert(val);
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        cin >> val;
        n2Ar.insert(val);
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n3; i++) {
        cin >> val;
        n3Ar.insert(val);
    }

    // Processing lists

    for (set<int>::iterator i = n1Ar.begin(); i != n1Ar.end(); ++i) {
        it = n2Ar.find(*i);

        if (it != n2Ar.end()) {
            list.insert(*i);
            n1Ar.erase(i);
            n2Ar.erase(it);

        } else {

            it = n3Ar.find(*i);
            if (it != n3Ar.end()) {
                list.insert(*i);
                n1Ar.erase(i);
                n3Ar.erase(it);
            }
        }
    }

    // Outputting the final list
    cout << list.size() << endl;
    for_each(list.begin(), list.end(), outputSet);

    return 0;
}
```

I hope you'll be able to help me understand what I am doing wrong in here. I am only starting with C++.

Comment: Please show us the exact error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

*First*, you need return a value in the following function, or simply make it return void.

```
// you should return a value here or make it return void
int outputSet(int i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

*Second*, the iterators in the following iterations of your for-loop are ***invalidated*** once you remove the current one. Once an element is removed, its iterator i is also invalidated, so as to the following iterators based on ++i;

And you'll get run-time error because iterator i now points to You need somehow "reset" it.

**MSVC Implementation**

```
for (set<int>::iterator i = n1Ar.begin(); i != n1Ar.end(); ++i) {
        it = n2Ar.find(*i);

        if (it != n2Ar.end()) {
            list.insert(*i);
            // the following iterators become invalidated after the
            // current one is removed. You need reset it like
            // i = n1Ar.erase(i);
            n1Ar.erase(i);
            n2Ar.erase(it);

        } else {

            it = n3Ar.find(*i);
            if (it != n3Ar.end()) {
                list.insert(*i);
                // the following iterators become invalidated after the
                // current one is removed. You need reset it like
                // i = n1Ar.erase(i);
                n1Ar.erase(i);
                n3Ar.erase(it);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: Note that returning a new iterator from set::erase() is not a Standard way. That's mainly for the purpose of performance.

**A More Portable Solution**

The basic idea is to correctly set the next iterator before removing the current one.

```
   set<int>::iterator i = n1Ar.begin();

   while (i != n1Ar.end())
   {
      it = n2Ar.find(*i);
      if (it != n2Ar.end())
      {
         // the trick is to use "i++" where i is incremented by one while "old" i
         // is removed.
         list.insert(*i);
         n1Ar.erase(i++);
         n2Ar.erase(it);
      }
      else
      {    
         it = n3Ar.find(*i);
         if (it != n3Ar.end())
         {
            list.insert(*i);
            n1Ar.erase(i++);
            n3Ar.erase(it);
         }
         else
         {
            ++i;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: The return value looks like the problem, but an `std::set` iterator isn't invalidated after an erase, and `std::set::erase` doesn't normally return an iterator (however, it does as a Visual Studio extension).

Comment: It does return an iterator in C++0x. Some Standard containers *do* return such an iterator in their interfaces in C++03.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried using `i = n1Ar.erase(i);` and I can't find a workaround of this compiler error: `error: no match for 'operator=' in 'i = n1Ar. std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::erase [with _Key = int, _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>](i)'` (I am using Netbeans 7.0.1)

Comment: @DeadMG, does it include associative containers like set?

Comment: @Hollgam, please try the second solution if you are not using MSVC. set::erase() is likely to return void in your implementation.

Comment: @Eric, I've tried using the second solution but I got confused about adding the part that works with `n3Ar` (starting from `it = n3Ar.find(*i);`) into else case following `++i`. Could you please help me a little further with this problem in this particular case. As I understand once `i` has been iterated I am no longer working with the same element of the set.

Comment: @Eric, ah stupid me. Now I got it working, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
n1Ar.erase(i);
```

The std::set::erase function invalidates the iterator i and causes the problem. Consider change to the following:

```
for (set<int>::iterator i = n1Ar.begin(); i != n1Ar.end(); ++i) {
        it = n2Ar.find(*i);

        if (it != n2Ar.end()) {
            list.insert(*i);
            i = n1Ar.erase(i);
            if(i == n1Ar.cend())
                break;
            n2Ar.erase(it);

        } else {
```

The `if(i == n1Ar.cend()) break;` check helps to ensure the invalidated iterator will not ruin the loop.

Comment: did you mean `.end()?`. If yes than I getting the same compiler error as with Eric's solution.

Comment: @Hollgam, cend() is the new stuff from c++0x. But it's not related to your issue here. The reason why you got compilation error is the 'i = n1Ar.erase(i)' is not old standard compliant. It really depends on the compiler you use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Erase method invalidates the iterator i.
2. [Erase](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/erase/) method does not return iterator.

**EDIT**: repeating Eric idea you can use the following code:

```
for (set<int>::iterator i = n1Ar.begin(); i != n1Ar.end(); )
    if ( n2Ar.erase(*i) || n3Ar.erase(*i) ) {
        list.insert(*i);
        n1Ar.erase(i++);
    } else i++;
```

Also this problem could be solved using standard algorithms. But this solution seems to be less efficient:

```
set<int> tmp;
std::set_union( n2Ar.begin(), n2Ar.end(),
    n3Ar.begin(), n3Ar.end(), std::inserter(tmp,tmp.begin()) );
std::set_intersection( n1Ar.begin(), n1Ar.end(),
    tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), std::inserter(list,list.begin()) );
```

Finally i suggest to use stl for your output (you have to include iterator library):

```
std::copy( list.begin(), list.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"));
```